# Code cleanup in Eclipse - How can I preserve blank lines in non-javadoc comments?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-cleanup

In all of my java source files I have a header that looks something like this.

```
/*
 * This file is part of the blah blah blah java library.
 * 
 * Copyright (C) 2014 myCompany Ltd.
 * 
 * e-mail : <me@myCompany.co.uk>, web : <www.myCompany.co.uk>
 */
```

I cannot seen to stop the eclipse Source code clean up from removing the blank lines.

By going to Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter, I can uncheck the 'Remove blank lines' option for javadoc comments but can't do the same for non-javadoc.
I've tried changing the 'Remove whitespace' in the Clean Up options.

I guess a simple answer would be to use javadoc style comments in my header but I notice that in the JDK code Oracle use non-javadoc style in the headings and have blank lines.

Trivial perhaps but it's bugging me.

Cheers

Simon

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`. Then edit profile by clicking `Edit...` button. In the Profile dialog, select `Blank Lines`. You will see that `Number of empty lines to preserve:` item. Set the value to 99 to preserve empty lines up to 99.

Now, when you format the code, it will preserve empty lines of non-javadoc codes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @nltabs, this is useful however it seems that blank lines do not get preserved inside c style multiline comments i.e. inside `/* Blah */` blocks. Oh well, I can live with this.